# Populate an attribute table "string" field with values from another "long" field (VB-script, ArcMap)

Tags: mysql, vbscript, arcgis

I want to calculate the field "area_type" with text depending on numbers from the "Value" field. I have tried with the following VB-script in "Field Calculator" but am getting this error message:

> The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1. For example, the calculated value may be too large for
>   the field or you may be trying to add a string to a number field. This
>   row will not be updated.

My "`area_type`" field type is **`string`** and "`Value`" is type **`long`**.

---

```
Dim area_type

Select Case [value]

  Case "1"

    area_type = "aapent omraade"
  Case "11"

    area_type = "bebygd"
  Case "12"

    area_type = "samferdsel"
  Case "21"

    area_type = "fulldyrka jord"
  Case "22"

    area_type = "overflatedyrka jord"
  Case "23"

    area_type = "innmarksbeite"
  Case "30"

    area_type = "skog"
  Case "50"

    area_type = "aapen fastmark"
  Case "60"

    area_type = "myr"
  Case "70"

    area_type = "isbre"
  Case "80"

    area_type = "vann"
  Case "99"

    area_type = "ruralt (ikke kartlagt)"
End Select
```

[image: Table and Field Calculator]

Comment: If it's long, then no need to put double quote around. Try without it, like instead of "`Case "1"`", use "`Case 1`".